# Parameter values results to error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've created a function to insert data different from displaying data. Then I get an error. Unknown column '$prod_name' in 'field list'. Please tell me any right suggestions because im a beginner in pdo. thanks

here is my code:

```
<?php
    function run_db($sqlcom){
        $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=product', 'root', '');
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlcom);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    function insertData($sqlcom)
    {
        $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=product', 'root', '');
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlcom);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }



    if(isset($_POST['btn-insert'])){

        $prodname = $_POST['prod_name'];
        $prodsupp = $_POST['prod_supplier'];
        $prodprice = $_POST['prod_price'];

        try{
            $stmt = insertData('INSERT INTO tbl_product(prod_name, prod_supplier, prod_price)VALUES($prodname, $prodsupp, $prodprice)');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die('error : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product ID</th>
                    <th>Product NAME</th>
                    <th>Product SUPPLIER</th>
                    <th>Product PRICE</th>
                </tr>
                <?php $stmt = run_db('SELECT * FROM tbl_product'); while($product = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $product->prod_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product->prod_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product->prod_supplier; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product->prod_price; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="prod_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product supplier:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="prod_supplier"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Price:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="prod_price"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btn-insert" value="INSERT"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For future reference: you are likely to get lots of downvotes when you yell at people on here by using all caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`s). Without them, a bareword is interpreted as an object (column, in this case) name, and the query fails when such an object doesn't exist.

To solve this issue, you could surround your inserted values with quotes:

```
$stmt = insertData("INSERT INTO tbl_product(prod_name, prod_supplier, prod_price)VALUES('$prodname', '$prodsupp', '$prodprice')");
```

Mandatory comment:
Using string replacement in SQL is a bad practice that leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: when i do that i got this error arse error: syntax error, unexpected '$prodname' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\databasepractice\index.php on line 28

Comment: @BluescriptCommunity forgot to replace the PHP single-quotes with double-quotes, my bad. Edited and fixed - try now.

Comment: when i try to change all single quotes to double quotes i got this error:( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$prodname' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\databasepractice\index.php on line 28

Comment: @BluescriptCommunity not all the quotes - just the surrounding two